# watching log file in C

Tags: python, c, file, loops, logfile

Using python, I have a daemon watching a log file in the following manner:

```
f = open(r'logfile.log', 'r')
while True:
    line = f.readline()
    if not line:
      time.sleep(1)
    else:
      # do something
```

Problem is, the 'do something' part would perform MUCH faster if it was written in C.  So, I would like to do the same in C.  How would the similar approach of tailing a log file be written in C?

The following just grabs the entire file, and does 'something' with each line.  Instead, I would like to only 'do something' with new lines appended to the log file :)

```
  FILE *fr;
  char line[100];
  fr = fopen ("logfile.log", "rt");
  while(fgets(line, 100, fr) != NULL){
      //do something
  }
  fclose(fr);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is "do something" actually doing?

Comment: @Blender doesnt matter.  Imagine its using sockets, sending shtuff, calling a function which runs 300 times faster than python/perl/bash :)

Comment: You can seek to the end of the file after opening it. Do you want to do it in C or in Python?

Comment: @joni in C :) and how would i not miss any additional lines ?  Imagine a log4j process writing a log file. I would like to tail that file, and do things with newly added lines

Comment: Have you tried getline()?

Comment: @twocode i've tried a few things.  Basically I need to write a function that watches a log file

Comment: Your `C` code will exit as soon as the log file isn't updated briefly, whereas your Python code continues looking. You need a `while (1)` loop.

Comment: Will this be running in linux?

Comment: @mbratch oh, how would that look?

Comment: I think @mbratch is right. You already did it in your Python code, an "infinite" `while` loop, but in your C version you wrote instead a loop which stops when it reaches the end of file.

Comment: Ah yes. I think @mbratch is answering what you've asked.

Comment: folks, kick ass, its working :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `fseek` function to skip to a particular offset in the file. To avoid skipping the new lines that were detected by the Python code, the part in python should pass the seek offset to the C code. (The best way to do that depends on how you're calling the C code..)

```
long seek_offset = /* get offset from Python side */
fseek(fr, seek_offset, SEEK_SET);
```

Answer (score 1):

I originally answered: “On a POSIX-like system, you can use `select()` to “watch” the open file-descriptor to see if any more input becomes available. This is probably the canonical way of doing it on any Unix/Linux system.”, but [I was wrong](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-03/msg00148.html).

I've used `select()` on sockets and pipes and assumed it would return only when there was more data available, but while this may be the superficial intuition, it is not actually the case: `select()` is defined to return when a subsequent `read()` (or `write()`) *will not block*, which is a different thing, because it is possible for `read()` to read zero bytes and not block.

An ordinary file is always `read()`-able, even at end-of-file. If you try to tail a log file using `select()`, `select()` never blocks, and subsequent `read()`s are zero-length. In short, you will end up busy waiting. Reading the source to any `tail` implementation, or reading [surrounding discussion](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-coreutils/2006-03/msg00148.html) will confirm this.

I thought I should leave this here, just in case anyone else should make the same mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try out the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
     mkfifo("tmpFifo");
     if(fork()==0)//to avoid the main program getting stuck at system()..
     {
          system("tail -f logfile.txt > tmpFifo");
          exit(0);
     }
     int fd = open("tmpFifo", O_RDONLY);
     char buff[1000];//set some length depending on the maximum string that gets 
                     //appended...
     int n;
     while((n=read(fd, buff, 1000))>0)
     {
         //do something... where 'n' stores the number of chars read...
     }
     close(fd);
     rm("tmpFifo");
     return 0;
}
```

In case you want to write the code rather than using `tail -f`, [this](http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/215107-tailing-log-file-using-c) might be helpful. But, I guess this is the simplest solution.

Comment: Will `system("tail -f logfile.txt > tmpFifo");` even return? The documentation for the call says, "returns after the command has been completed", but the `tail -f` doesn't complete unless it receives a KILL signal from somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated the answer accordingly...
Edit: You can also use the `exec` call instead. For simplicity, I still preferred using `system()`.